# Why do I get 'syntax error at Email/MIME/CreateHTML.pm line 203, near "croak "You must supply a body""' when I use Email::MIME::CreateHTML?

Tags: perl

I'm using the CPAN module [Email::MIME::CreateHTML](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME::CreateHTML) but keep getting the following error:

> syntax error at Email/MIME/CreateHTML.pm line 203, near "croak "You must supply a body""

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;

use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS;
use Email::MIME::CreateHTML;

my $SendTo = 'MyEmail@SendTo.com';
my $SendFrom = 'MyEmail@SendFrom.com';
my $Subject = 'test MSG';

my $SMTP_Server = 'smtp.gmail.com';
my $SMTP_SSL = 'starttls';
my $SMTP_Port = 587;
my $SMTP_User   = 'my@gmail.com';
my $SMTP_Password = 'MyGmailPassword';

my $eMailMessage = "Test MSG";

use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS;
use Email::MIME::CreateHTML;

my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS->new({
  host => $SMTP_Server,
  ssl  => $SMTP_SSL,
  port => $SMTP_Port,
  sasl_username => $SMTP_User,
  sasl_password => $SMTP_Password,
  debug => 1,
});


my $email = Email::MIME->create_html(
  header => [
    To      => $SendTo,
    From    => $SendFrom,
    Subject => $Subject,
  ],

 body => $eMailMessage

);

sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });

print 'Mail Sent';
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: is `$eMailMessage` populated with any data?

Comment: Yes, all variables populated

Comment: How sure are you? Have you printed it out to verify that? The code in the module checks if `body` has a *true* value, and if not, it croaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have an old version of Email::MIME::CreateHTML. This looks like a [bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=53921) that was fixed in version 1.030:

> This happens because the `create_html` method being mixed into Email::MIME does not have `croak` in scope. The fix is to simply explicitly load Carp again after the `package Email::MIME` declaration.
>
> I'm not sure exactly how this ever worked, honestly.

Upgrade to the latest version.